# How do I fix this error in Big Query?: Syntax error: Expected end of input but got "(" at [3:11]

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I can't seem to find a solution to the following error. I have tried using " ",   and ' ' around start_station_name to no avail. I have moved the () around as well. I can't seem to find a solution to the error. No matter what I do, I keep receiving the same syntax error message: "Syntax error: Expected end of input but got "(" at [3:11]"

Any help would be appreciated!

```
SELECT 
    usertype
    CONCAT(start_station_name,"to",end_station_name) AS route
    COUNT(*)as num_trips,
    ROUND(AVG(cast(tripduration as int64)/60),2) AS duration
FROM 
    `bigquery-public-data.new_york.citibike_trips`
GROUP BY 
    start_station_name, end_station_name, usertype
ORDER BY 
    num_trips DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: You just simply missing commas to separate output columns in select statement. And actually no any issues with group by!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to put a comma after usertype in line #2. The columns in GROUP BY are also in conflict with the columns in SELECT. Try to implement sub query like this -

```
SELECT t1.usertype, t1.start_station_name, t1.end_station_name,
CONCAT(t1.start_station_name,"to",t1.end_station_name) AS route, 
t1.num_trips, t1.duration
FROM ( SELECT usertype, start_station_name, end_station_name, 
       COUNT(*)as num_trips , 
       ROUND(AVG(cast(tripduration as int64)/60),2) AS duration 
       from `bigquery-public-data.new_york.citibike_trips`
       GROUP BY usertype, start_station_name, end_station_name 
     ) t1
ORDER BY t1.num_trips DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Use GROUP BY in inner sub query and use CONCAT in outer sub-query

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue with this query from week 2 of Analyze Data course of the Google Data Analytics Professional Certificate program offered through Coursera.  I noticed in the schema that the trip duration was already an integer, so there is no need to caste is as an integer.  When I took that part out, it ran fine.

```
SELECT usertype, 
  CONCAT(start_station_name," to ",end_station_name) AS route, 
  COUNT (*) as num_trips,
  ROUND (AVG(tripduration/60), 2) AS duration
FROM 
    `bigquery-public-data.new_york.citibike_trips`
GROUP BY 
  usertype, start_station_name, end_station_name 
ORDER BY 
  num_trips DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Hey Amanda, that's a good catch. Yes, this works on the console!

Answer (score 0):

Same issue while completing the Google Data Analytics
Cert provided through Coursera, I had to add commas after line 2, 3, and 4 and then it ran fine[BigQuery screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmuhG.png)

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)